# Can not connect to local address in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, connection-string

Cannot create SQL connection with this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Database=SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

but there's no problem with this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-7M2F9E2\MOJTABA;Database=SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Why can it not connect to `local`?

Comment: Have you tried `.\MOJTABA`?

Comment: Is the server supposed to be "Server=.;". is it not missing?

Comment: Well - do you **have** a default (unnamed) SQL Server instance on your local machine?? If you install SQL Server *Express*, you typically get a `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance - might that be the problem? Or did you just simply not install any SQL Server database engine on your local machine??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's most probably cause you are trying to connect to a named instance called `MOJTABA` and not to a default instance as can be seen from your posted code `connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-7M2F9E2\MOJTABA`. You can as well say `Server=localhost\MOJTABA` or `.\MOJTABA`

Comment: You can definitely use `.\MOJTABA`, if there is a named instance called `MOJTABA` on the local machine ...

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=.\MOJTABA;Database=SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

`Server=.\MOJTABA` means: local machine (.), MOJTABA database server instance.
The dot alone is not enough to know which instance to connect to.

Comment: The dot alone connects to the **default, unnamed** instance of SQL Server - it **IS** enough to know where to go! That instance just has to exist, too .....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C# problem, so the tag for that was wrong. The Network code does not care if the other end is on the same computer, same switch or the Voyager 2 Probe.

Proper installation and administration of a SQL Server is a totally seperate mater from programming.

And finally connection strings are a mater so complicated, there is a [dedicated webpage](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) for that.

This is either a SQL Server Administration issue (the instance you try to connect does not exists/is not allowed to take connections) or a Connection String issue (you formated it faulty). It is really impossible to tell without knowing how exactly your Environment looks, wich is something only you can realy do.

Comment: And this is not an answer.  If you want to comment on the validity and content of a question, then use the comments, not an answer even if you have a lot to say.

Comment: @juharr The answer is: "It is one of those two, but we can not say wich one precisely." It is one of those problems where we could write whole books of possible causes and still not answer his question precisely, because we simply do not know the exact situation on his computer at this very moment.

Comment: Then the question is either lacking information or it's too broad.  You can vote to close it for either reason, but explaining that is not an answer.

Comment: @juharr: There is nothing wrong with the question so I see no reason to close it. It is as valid as everything I ever asked. It is the nature of this **problem** (wich is not a uncommon one) that makes answering guesswork to diretion giving at best. It is the same as any case of a Race Condition: We can only give rought directions to the solution. The actuall solution requires a full understanding of the code wich we do not have or a major design change.

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with the question either, but your answer seems to indicate that there is.  I'm saying you cannot have it both ways, a question that is "good", but an answer that indicates that it's to vague or missing information to give a detailed answer.  That I personally think you're wrong about that is another issue altogether.

Comment: @juharr: I am not saying the answer is to vague or missing information. I am saying. "Problem is by nature nearly impossible to debug. This is the best I can give you".